# RegularExpressionAttribute behaves different to Regex or RegexStringValidator

Tags: c#, regex, entity-framework

I use [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) on my EF meta data like so:

```
[RegularExpression("[A-Z]+")]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

And it correctly does not let me enter anything other than A-Z anywhere in the field.

Elsewhere I want to use the same reg expressions in code, so I turned to Regex like so:

```
var regex = new Regex("[A-Z]+");
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("B")); //true
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("1")); //false
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("A1")); //true - why?
```

Also [RegexStringValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.regexstringvalidator.aspx) works the same as Regex.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> var regex = new Regex("[A-Z]+");
> Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("A1")); //true - why?
> ```

That regex says to match one or more upper case latin letters. And "`A1`" contains an upper case latin letter.

By default regexes match *anywhere* in the string. To match the whole string start with a "`^`" *start of string anchor* and end with a "`$`" *end of string anchor*:

```
 var regex = new Regex("^[A-Z]+$");
 Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("A1"));
```

will show `false`.

(There are a whole set of [anchors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions) in .NET regular expressions.)

Comment: Thanks, any idea about why I don't need to anchor the expression in RegularExpressionAttribute?

Comment: @weston [Speculative] Because with the attribute you almost certainly want to match the whole thing, so this is defaulted by some mechanism (this is a case of the attribute doing the right thing by default). The lack of default "match whole string" reflects in part the history of regexes and their use for splitting strings and multiple matches neither of which apply with field validation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want this:

```
"^[A-Z]+$"
```

`"[A-Z]+"` will match one or more letters, no metter what position they have inside of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You must anchor your regular expression

```
"^[A-Z]$"
```